# Remove titlebar from maximized terminal window

Tags: command-line, xfce, titlebar

I'm using XFCE on 10.10 and this is just one of those "is this even possible" type questions.

When I have the terminal maximized, is it possible to remove the titlebar, including the close, minimize and maximize buttons?

In essence, it'd be nice to have a fully maximized, transparent terminal overlay.  I tend to use terminal text editors alot, and this would be an interesting effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://xrunhprof.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/removing-decoration-in-xfwm-or-metacity-again/) should do what you want:

Copy and paste this into your favourite text editor:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from gtk.gdk import *

w=window_foreign_new((get_default_root_window().property_get("_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW")[2][0]))
state = w.property_get("_NET_WM_STATE")[2]
maximized='_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ' in state and '_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT' in state
if maximized: w.unmaximize()
if w.get_decorations() == 0 :
    w.set_decorations(DECOR_ALL)
else:
    w.set_decorations(0)

if maximized: w.maximize()
window_process_all_updates()
```

save in your home folder with the name *decoration.py*

Add execute permissions:

```
chmod +x ~/decoration.py
```

Create a keyboard shortcut:

[image]

For the shortcut in the picture - maximize your terminal and type <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to remove the window decoration in the terminal.

[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for!  Thanks!  Only issue it takes two ALT-Y keypresses to get it working, but other than that...

Comment: A nice script, thanks. It worked intermittently with foobar+wine, fixed it by commenting out all the refs to "maximixed".

Comment: How could I apply this to all applications on startup?

Comment: me too. all windows at startup