# Executing script with terminal via command option

Tags: command-line

I implemented the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75284/remove-titlebar-from-maximized-terminal-window/75291#75291) and now the title bar is gone from the terminal.  I found that the python script `decorator.py` had to execute twice to have the effect applied.  Rather than tapping out `./decorator.py` twice every time I started a new terminal, I created `maximize` to execute the script twice.  This script is hotkeyed to Ctrl-Alt-Y.

Currently I've used

`gnome-terminal --maximize -e /home/jason/maximize`

`gnome-terminal --maximize -x /home/jason/maximize`

as arguments for Ctrl-Alt-T.

The issue is I can see the outline of a new terminal flash on screen, but it doesn't exist for more than a fraction of a second.  How can I make the new window more persistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-x` option to
[gnome-terminal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gnome-terminal) or,
similarly, the `-e` option to other xterm-compatible terminal
applications, tell the terminal emulator to start the command
following the `-x`/`-e` option and then exit.  This is the reason why
you're seeing the terminal outline flash and disappear: the terminal
starts, maximizes, then exits.

You could instead include the `maximize` command into your `.bashrc`
or `.profile`, so that it is executed every time a shell is started.

However, since it executed each time a shell is started, you need to
find a way to execute it only when the shell is started from the
terminal application.  On my Ubuntu 11.04 system the following does
the trick:

```bsh
if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ] && [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
  # the following commands are only executed when
  # the shell runs inside a terminal
  maximize
fi
```

The `-n "$DISPLAY"` part tests if there is a graphical X11 display
active, and the `$SHLVL` part checks if this shell is 1st level shell,
i.e., a direct child of the terminal application (a shell may start
another shell for running commands or script, but in this case the
`$SHLVL` value will be larger than 1).