# How do I start an application maximized without decorations in gnome-shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, fullscreen

There is a possibility to configure application (for me darktable) that start in full screen mode without the title bar (I use GNOME Shell in Ubuntu 11.10)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

This was achieved using `devilspie` to start `darktable` maximised, followed by my linked answer to remove the window decoration.

Note - I tried this with the devilspie "undecorate" command but that just left an annoying blank space where the decoration would be

**install devilspie**

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie
mkdir ~/.devilspie
nano ~/.devilspie/darktable.ds
```

copy and paste the following:

```
  (is (application_name) "darktable")
    (begin
       (maximize)
       (spawn_sync "/home/dad/decoration.py")
       (spawn_sync "/home/dad/decoration.py")
    )
```

N.B. substitute `/home/dad/decoration.py` for the full-pathname to the undecorate script.  Save.

Finally, make sure `devilspie` start in your startup-applications.

---

Linked Question:

1. [Remove titlebar from maximized terminal window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75284/remove-titlebar-from-maximized-terminal-window/75291#75291)

Comment: Great! If script run automatically when I launch darktable - will be perfect. I change 'fullscreen' (in darktable.ds) to 'maximaze'.

Comment: ... ok give my amendment a try!

Answer (score 1):

You use F11 key in darktable to enter/leave fullscreen state, this state
is also stored upon exit so next time you start darktable it will be
fullscreen as default.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that. My question may be misleading, but panel need to be visible (I use often workspace indicator)

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Compiz, you could use the window rules plugin, but since you are using Gnome Shell, to my knowledge, there is nothing you can do.