# Hide window title in gnome-shell using mutter, gdk, wnck or gtk

Tags: gnome, gtk, metacity, gtk3

I'm after a way to:

1. get list of all application windows currently open, as a Gdk or Gtk window
2. remove window decorations for selected windows (maximised in my case).

I'd like to do this using mutter, gdk, wnck or gtk (or GdkX11, ...) (i.e. anything with gobject introspection).

I've seen the following question: [Remove titlebar from maximized terminal window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75284/remove-titlebar-from-maximized-terminal-window/75291#75291) but am struggling with converting it to something that works.

(The language I'm using is javascript, but this is somewhat irrelevant since it's all using gobject introspection).

I'm currently using GNOME 3.2 (am open to GNOME 3.4 solutions though).

---

As to **1.**, I know I can get all windows with `wnck` and `mutter` fairly easily (e.g. `Wnck.Screen.get_default().get_windows()`), but how do I then convert these into G(t or d?)k windows in order to remove decorations?

I can convert a mutter window to a Gdk one like so:

```
xwin = GdkX11.X11Window.foreign_new_for_display( 
                          Gdk.Display.get_default(), 
                          mutterWindow.get_compositor_private()['x-window'] );
```

*However*, this `xwin` object does not respond to commands such as `xwin.unmaximize()` and `xwin.maximize()`, so I feel that something went wrong in the conversion!

The reason I want to convert the window into Gdk or Gtk is so I can use Gdk's [`set_decorations`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-decorations) or Gtk's [`set_hide_titlebar_when_maximized`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-hide-titlebar-when-maximized).

I have had a look at `Gdk.Screen.get_default().get_toplevel_windows()` and `Gtk.Window.list_toplevels()` but these return lists of more windows than I have open, and I am unsure if my actual application windows are in the list and how to match them up.

---

As to **2.**, if I first get the active window from within Gdk (since I know it's a Gdk window and it responds properly to events such as `unmaximize` and `maximize`, unlike when I use `foreign_new_for_display`) and then try to remove decoration as per the previously linked question, the window (& process) dies! I'm not sure what the error is.

```
const Gdk = imports.gi.Gdk;

// get current window. It's a terminal, not null.
// For now assume it's maximized.
curwin = Gdk.Screen.get_default().get_active_window();
// decorations don't seem to updated unless I unmaximize & re-maximize
curwin.unmaximize();
// try remove decorations: window + process dies!
curwin.set_decorations(0);
curwin.maximize();
```

If I use `curwin.set_decorations(Gdk.WMDecoration.BORDER)` (note: GDK window documentation [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html)), the window appears as I wish when the window is unmaximized (title bar gone), but when maximized, space for the title bar is still left, although the text itself is not shown.

---

Would anyone be able to give me insight into how to achieve either of my goals? (Ultimately, automagic titlebar hiding of maximised windows, like `maximus` for Ubuntu's Unity netbook remix). I really do wish to use this using Gtk/Gdk/wnck/mutter/anything with gobject introspection, as opposed to an external app like compiz or modifying the metacity window theme's XML (which I know you can do to achieve this).

Comment: I think the mutter --> gdk window conversion might not be working because the window actor's `x-window` property appears not to be the correct `xid`: if I get the same window as a Wnck window, `win.get_xid()` is different to `mutterWinActor['x-window']` and the wnck-->gdk window works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of discussion with the gnome-shell devs, this was resolved.

The conversion I attempted to do in 1. was never an option - that sort of thing doesn't work.

The version in 2. was the correct code, but would only work if run from *outside* a gnome-shell extension (i.e. run the javascript file using the `gjs` binary as opposed to from the looking glass or an extension). It turned out that mucking around with window decorations like that from within the gnome-shell/mutter process would cause the crash.

So the problem could be solved so long as the code was run from *outside* the extension. Launching an external process to run the script in option 2) worked (although it turned out to be easier to just spawn `xprop` and set the `_GTK_HIDE_TITLEBAR_WHEN_MAXIMIZED` atom to `true` on the window (identified by its X ID, being the *child* of the window with the window actor's XID).

(If anyone is interested the end result is the [Maximus gnome shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/354/maximus/))

Comment: I use that extention with a patched version of https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/426/window-buttons/ (see pull request on github). It work great and I really enjor to get some pixel back !